# Função remove lista encadeada

Tags: python, c, memória, alocação

Salve pessoal, estou aprendendo lista encadeadas em python, como já possuo algum conhecimento de lista em C me bateu dúvida sobre remoção de  nodos, a base dos algoritmos que usei em alguns exercícios é esse:

```
Algorithm remove_first(L):
    if L.head is None then
        Indicate an error: the list is empty.
    L.head = L.head.next 
    L.size = L.size−1
```

Fiquei com dúvida sobre vazamento de memória. Como a remoção de nodos aparentemente funciona apenas com uma troca de ponteitos, fiquei com dúvida se a memória, com essa troca, fica alocada e inacessível ou não, se a troca já torna disponível a memória? Pensei na função free de C, existe algum método análogo em python para tornar disponível a memória? Se o caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está pergunta já foi respondida no SO em inglês.

Python usa `garbage collector` para o controle de memória. Deste modo, em tempos o gc limpa a memória liberando os objetos que não estão referenciados.

Portanto, usando o comando `del` vc pode marcar o objeto como "deletável" e o gc irá, em algum momento, liberar a memória usada por este objeto.

Fonte:

[How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python)

[Documentação Oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html)